# Yahtzee - Java - Error

Tags: java, dice

I am trying to do a Yahtzee program. I start with trying to get the card pairs to work out before I continue with rest.

```
    public class PlayEngine {
public PlayEngine(){}
public int evaluate(int[] dicePoints){

double dice1 = Math.random()*6+1;
         int diceint1 = (int) dice1;
    double dice2 = Math.random()*6+1;
         int diceint2 = (int) dice2;
         double dice3 = Math.random()*6+1;
         int diceint3 = (int) dice3;
   double dice4 = Math.random()*6+1;
         int diceint4 = (int) dice4;
   double dice5 = Math.random()*6+1;
         int diceint5 = (int) dice5;     

   /* int[] dicePoints = {dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5};    */

  int par = 0;

      if(dice1==dice2 || dice1==dice3 || dice1==dice4 || dice1==dice5 || dice2==dice3 || dice2==dice4 || dice2==dice5 || dice3==dice4 || dice3==dice5 || dice4==dice5) 
     {
  par = 1;
  return par;

      } else {  
    return par;
      }
   } //dicePoints
} //PlayEngine
```

When I run this, I get no errors. I only get up the "No main methods..", and that is how it should be.

When I try to run the program we got from school to test if the score:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestScore {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] dicePoints = new int[5];
      int[] playPoints = new int[15];
      PlayEngine player = new PlayEngine ();
      String[] kategori = {"Ettor         ",
                           "Tvåor         ",
                           "Treor         ",
                           "Fyror         ",
                           "Femmor        ",
                           "Sexor         ",
                           "Par           ",
                           "Två Par       ",
                           "Triss         ",
                           "Fyrtal        ",
                           "Liten stege   ",
                           "Stor stege    ",
                           "Kåk           ",
                           "Chans         ",
                           "Yatzy         "};
      String indata, utdata;
      while(true) {
         indata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange tärningarnas värden: ");
         if (indata == null)  // Avsluta genom att trycka Cancel
            break;
         StringTokenizer ordSeparator = new StringTokenizer(indata, " ,\t");
         if (ordSeparator.countTokens() == 5) {
            int index = 0;
            while(ordSeparator.hasMoreTokens() && index < 5) {
               String ettOrd = ordSeparator.nextToken();
               dicePoints[index] = Integer.parseInt(ettOrd);;
               index = index + 1;
            }
            playPoints = player.evaluate(dicePoints);
            utdata = "Tärningarnas värden: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < dicePoints.length; i = i + 1)
               utdata = utdata + dicePoints[i] + "   ";
            utdata = utdata + "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
               utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + playPoints[i] + "\n";
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, utdata);
         }
         else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har angivt felaktigt antal värden!!!");
      }
   }//main
} //TestScore
```

I get this error:

```
TestScore.java:36: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
        playPoints = player.evaluate(dicePoints);
                                    ^
```

How come? What is wrong?

Updated code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestScore {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] dicePoints = new int[5];
      int playPoints;
      PlayEngine player = new PlayEngine ();
      String[] kategori = {"Ettor         ",
                           "Tvåor         ",
                           "Treor         ",
                           "Fyror         ",
                           "Femmor        ",
                           "Sexor         ",
                           "Par           ",
                           "Två Par       ",
                           "Triss         ",
                           "Fyrtal        ",
                           "Liten stege   ",
                           "Stor stege    ",
                           "Kåk           ",
                           "Chans         ",
                           "Yatzy         "};
      String indata, utdata;
      while(true) {
         indata = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange tärningarnas värden: ");
         if (indata == null)  // Avsluta genom att trycka Cancel
            break;
         StringTokenizer ordSeparator = new StringTokenizer(indata, " ,\t");
         if (ordSeparator.countTokens() == 5) {
            int index = 0;
            while(ordSeparator.hasMoreTokens() && index < 5) {
               String ettOrd = ordSeparator.nextToken();
               dicePoints[index] = Integer.parseInt(ettOrd);;
               index = index + 1;
            }
            playPoints = player.evaluate(dicePoints);
            utdata = "Tärningarnas värden: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < dicePoints.length; i = i + 1)
               utdata = utdata + dicePoints[i] + "   ";

            utdata = utdata + "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
               utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + player.evaluate(dicePoints) + "\n";

            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, utdata);
         }
         else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har angivt felaktigt antal värden!!!");
      }
   }//main
} //TestScore
```

Answer (score 0):

`evaluate` method return `int` (defined as `public int evaluate(int[] dicePoints){`) and not `int[]`. You are trying to save value returned from evaluate method as an array here:

```
playPoints = player.evaluate(dicePoints);
```

as you defined `playPoints` variable as `int[] playPoints = new int[15];`

Change it to `int playPoints;`

Comment: I changed int[] playPoints = new int[15]; to int playPoints;

And got these errors:
`TestScore.java:41: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
                                         ^
TestScore.java:42: error: array required, but int found
               utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + playPoints[i] + "\n";`

What to do?

Comment: change `playPoints.length` to `dicePoints.length` in the for loop above. and change ` utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + playPoints[i] + "\n";` to ` utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + playPoints + "\n";`

Comment: Now it works :) But I get what points on dices I entered. I dont get up if it's pair or something.

Comment: in that case you may need to call `playPoints = player.evaluate(dicePoints);` in your for loop.

Comment: I have two foor-loops. Should I just add them below the "utdata"? Tried that, but got same result.

Comment: add it in this loop `for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
               utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + playPoints[i] + "\n";
            }` like `for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
               utdata = utdata + kategori[i] + player.evaluate(dicePoints) + "\n"; ` but it will evaluate same value so not sure what exactly you need here.
            }`

Comment: Getting this error:

TestScore.java:42: error: int cannot be dereferenced
            for (int i = 0; i <playPoints.length; i = i + 1) {
                                         ^
1 error

What to do?

Comment: I did. But I still dont get it. I changed what you told me to change and still getting error.